# Increase value of numericUpDown by 1 and press a button at the same time

Tags: c#, function, button, numericupdown

I'm trying to make a function which can be used to increase the value of a numericUpDown and press a button at the same time but this is giving me problems any idea how to make it better ? Making a project and need this function so i don't need to create a new case that is  if a person wants to choose all then it goes from value 1 to 10 and each time the button is clicked along with it.

```
    private void PlusClick(NumericUpDown numericUpDown, Button button, int start, int stop)
    {
        for (start = (int)numericUpDown.Value; start < stop;)
        {
            numericUpDown.UpButton();
            button.PerformClick();
            start++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "giving you problems"?  Is it throwing an error?

Comment: The thing is suppose if i do :

PlusClick(numericUpDown1, button1, 1, 10);

it just jumps to 10 and performs the click and i want it to go one by one and perform click. (so move up the numericUpDown by 1 and click button the number of times i choose)

Comment: You mean, you want to animate it going from 1 to 10?  What's the button_click event code doing?

Comment: Yea you can say that, how can you help ? or how would you come up with a better idea ?

Comment: Add a `Thread.Sleep(100);` followed by `this.Refresh();` inside your for...loop.  This will lock the GUI until it's done.

Comment: Tried that already it just froze the debugging too.